# How can show just text "Pinterest" instead of pinit button using AddThis plugin

Tags: php, wordpress, addthis

Pinterest just text is not shown instead of pinit button, but facebook and Twitter text is shown only Pinterest text is not shown.

here is my code:

```
<div class="addthis_toolbox addthis_default_style addthis_32x32_style">
<a class="addthis_button_facebook">Facebook</a>
<a class="addthis_button_twitter">Twitter</a>
**<a class="addthis_button_pinterest_pinit">Pinterest</a>**
```

Comment: Can you please provide a link to the site? It would be helpful to see any css and the context of this code.

Comment: @RyanSmith sorry site is under development, I can provide you screenshot,please find the attached screenshot. Here the text is totally hided, but for others text is shown.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to find the pintrest button image you're looking for and just overwrite the current image with a css rule.

```
.addthis_button_pinterest_pinit {

    background-image: url('path/to/new/image.png') !important;/*make sure you have !important!*/

    background-size: contain;

}
```